# Asp.net SSRS 2008 (RDLC) export to Excel Report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I need to write a SSRS Report (RDLC) with Sub Report and directly export the report to Excel on asp.net button click event.

Could someone please help me with whether this can be done without having to install SSRS i.e. no liscense required?

The SSRS Report needs to render each Groups in to separate sheet.e.g. if there are 3 States, the report should show the data for each states in to different excel sheets.

I tried to do this with Crystal report, but crystal report doesn't support multiiple sheets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that every option to parse SSRS reports available from Microsoft requires a license and installation, either on the server or on the client, wherever the .rdl is parsed. (Does Microsoft distribute any software that doesn't require some sort of license agreement?)

But some of the licenses do not require purchase and are freely available. .rdlc files can be parsed and displayed in a ReportViewer control, which requires .NET and the ["Microsoft Report Viewer 2010 Redistributable Package"](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6442)
If you look on that page, you'll see that SSRS is only required for Server processing mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property "Pagebreak" you have to set on the tablix or table or other element to force a new tab, and then set the property "Pagename" on both the element before the pagebreak and the element after the pagebreak. These names will appear on the tabs when the report is exported to Excel. For more info : [Report Design: Naming Excel Worksheets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/16/report-design-naming-excel-worksheets.aspx) and [Exporting to Microsoft Excel (Report Builder and SSRS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx).

Comment: This is for RDL only correct?  I'm trying to get Sheet names for RDLC in vs 2008 fixed   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577284/asp-net-ssrs-2008-rdlc-export-to-excel-report-with-naming-of-sheets